# UICollectionView isPagingEnabled

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview

I have a problem with a horizontal scroll in `collectionView`.

I want to scroll by section. I have 3 sections. I want to center it in the view.

First, it looks how I want

[image]

But when I scroll next... Left and right insets are different.

[image]

The last one is broken too.

[image]

I tried it with function `scrollViewDidEndDecelerating`, but it didn't work. Animation of it was ugly.

My code of `collectionView` layout.

```
    let layout = UICollectionViewFlowLayout()
    layout.sectionInset = UIEdgeInsets(top: 0, left: 15, bottom: 0, right: 15)
    layout.minimumLineSpacing = 5
    layout.scrollDirection = .horizontal
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to implement `UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout` methods to solve this problem.

```
let minLineSpace = 4

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView,
                    layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout,
                    sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize {

    return CGSize(width: UIScreen.main.bounds.width - minLineSpace, height: collectionView.frame.size.height)
}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, minimumLineSpacingForSectionAt section: Int) -> CGFloat {
    return minLineSpace
}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, insetForSectionAt section: Int) -> UIEdgeInsets {
    return UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, (minLineSpace / 2), 0, (minLineSpace / 2))
}
```

Here I have added 4 point spacing between two cells, you can customise this as per your requirement.